# Add types for a react js form validation schema

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the next situation:

```
interface FORM<P> {
  onSubmit: (d: P) => void;
  schema?: yup.SchemaOf<P>;
}
```

This is how my `onSubmit` looks:

```
 const onSubmit = (d: { firstName: string; lastName: string }) => {
    console.log(d);
  };
```

This is how my `schema` looks:

```
const schema = yup.object({
  firstName: yup.string().required('name'),
  lastName: yup.string(),
});
```

Adding the prop in my component:

```
 <Test
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
      schema={schema}
    >
```

...i get the next Typescript error:

```
TS2322: Type 'OptionalObjectSchema<{ firstName: RequiredStringSchema<string | undefined, AnyObject>; lastName: StringSchema<string | undefined, AnyObject, string | undefined>; }, AnyObject, TypeOfShape<...>>' is not assignable to type 'ObjectSchema<{ firstName: BaseSchema<Maybe<string>, AnyObject, string>; lastName: BaseSchema<Maybe<string>, AnyObject, string>; }, AnyObject, TypeOfShape<...>, AssertsShape<...>>'.   The types of 'fields.lastName.__outputType' are incompatible between these types.     Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.       Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Note: i uses `yup` and `react hook forms`. 

 Question: How to solve the issue above?

Comment: `lastName` is not required in your schema but it is in `onSubmit`, just like the error message clearly explains.

Comment: @super, then how to avoid the TS issue keeping the same onsubmit type definition? Maybe there is a way to change this: `schema?: yup.SchemaOf<P>;` ? Could you help? Somehow to change `P` type to avoid the issue?

Comment: @super, i used this `yup.SchemaOf<{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends undefined ? string : T[K] }>;` but it does not help.

Comment: Just make `lastName` optional in `onSubmit`. Or make `lastName` required in your schema.

Comment: @super, it is possible here `yup.SchemaOf<P>;` to check if P has a key, in our case `lastName` required, to make it optional, to be able to achieve what i described above?

Comment: @super changing lastName optional in onSubmit i think is a lit a bit unclear, because it strange when a parameter is optional within a function. Also making the lastName required in schema also i thin is not correct because i don't want it to be required as a type, it should be optional from Yup perspective. Could you help?

Comment: @super, from my perspective, the schema should not depend by `onSubmit` data type. It should take into account these values, but not to depend by it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix the error displayed above, it should be either marked in schema to make the `lastName` required as below;

```
const schema = yup.object({
  firstName: yup.string().required('firstName'),
  lastName: yup.string().required('lastName'),
});
```

or make it optional within the schema as well like below;

```
const schema = yup.object({
  firstName: yup.string().required('name'),
  lastName?: yup.string(),
});
```